# Unable to stream HTML video element to backend server using Webrtc, JS & Python backend

Tags: javascript, python, webrtc, video-streaming, p2p

I have been trying to create a web app with 3 modes - namely "use-webcam", "use-file" and "validation".
When use-webcam is selected, video track/stream from webcam is stream to the python backend and the file is saved once the stream ends, and this works fine.
When use-file is selected, we get a option to upload a file and use this file to stream to the backend and run my processes.
When validation is selected, we get a list of all the files we processsed until now and the  selected video is used as the input to for further processing.

So the whole setup works for the use-webcam mode and doesn't work for other modes.

This is my existing client.js script.

```
var dataChannelLog = document.getElementById('data-channel'),
    uidlog = document.getElementById('uid')
iceConnectionLog = document.getElementById('ice-connection-state'),
    iceGatheringLog = document.getElementById('ice-gathering-state'),
    signalingLog = document.getElementById('signaling-state');

var pc = null;
var dc;
var timerInterval = null;
var timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
var plotted_data = null;
var plotted_time = null;

const useFileChecked = document.getElementById("use-file").checked;
const useWebcam = document.getElementById("use-webcam").checked;
const Validation = document.getElementById("validation").checked;

const fileInput = document.querySelector('input#file');
const video = document.getElementById("video");
const progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
const process = document.getElementById("start-process");
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
const videoUpload = document.getElementById("video-upload");

var uid = "";
var uploaded_filepath = "";
var mode = "";
var upload_details;
var stream;

// get selected value from video-selection dropdown
const selectedVideo = document.getElementById("video-selection");

// display selected video name in selectedVideo div
selectedVideo.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const result = document.getElementById("selectedVideo");
    result.textContent = "./INPUT_VIDEOS/" + event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value)
    uploaded_filepath = "./INPUT_VIDEOS/" + event.target.value;
});

function populateDropdown(filePaths) {
    const videoSelection = document.getElementById("video-selection");
    videoSelection.innerHTML = ""
    for (const filePath of filePaths) {
        const option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.setAttribute('value', filePath);
        option.textContent = filePath;
        option.style.display = "inline";
        videoSelection.appendChild(option);
    }
};

function toggleElements() {
    const useVideoChecked = document.getElementById("use-webcam").checked;
    const validationChecked = document.getElementById("validation").checked;
    const useFileChecked = document.getElementById("use-file").checked;
    const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
    const stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
    const videoSelection = document.getElementById("video-selection");
    const timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    const file = document.getElementById("file");
    const progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    const upload = document.getElementById("upload");
    const process = document.getElementById("start-process");

    if (useVideoChecked) {
        mode = "use-webcam";
        startButton.style.display = "inline";
        stopButton.style.display = "inline";
        timer.style.display = "inline";
        file.style.display = "none";
        videoSelection.style.display = "none";
        upload.style.display = "none";
        video.autoplay = true;
    } else if (validationChecked) {
        mode = "validation";
        startButton.style.display = "inline";
        stopButton.style.display = "inline";
        timer.style.display = "inline";
        file.style.display = "none";
        video.style.display = "none";
        videoSelection.style.display = "inline";
        upload.style.display = "none";
        fetch('/get_file_paths')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.filePaths)
                populateDropdown(data.filePaths);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching file paths:', error);
            });
    } else {
        mode = "use-file";
        startButton.style.display = "none";
        stopButton.style.display = "none";
        file.style.display = "block";
        videoSelection.style.display = "none";
        upload.style.display = "inline";
    }
};

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function (radio) {
    radio.addEventListener("change", toggleElements);
});

toggleElements();


var time_start = null;
function current_stamp() {
    if (time_start === null) {
        time_start = new Date().getTime();
        return 0;
    } else {
        return new Date().getTime() - time_start;
    }
};

function createPeerConnection() {
    var config = {
        sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan'
    };
    var config = {
        iceServers: [{ urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'] }]
    };
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

    pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', function () {
        iceGatheringLog.textContent += ' -> ' + pc.iceGatheringState;
    }, false);
    iceGatheringLog.textContent = pc.iceGatheringState;

    pc.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', function () {
        iceConnectionLog.textContent += ' -> ' + pc.iceConnectionState;
    }, false);
    iceConnectionLog.textContent = pc.iceConnectionState;

    pc.addEventListener('signalingstatechange', function () {
        signalingLog.textContent += ' -> ' + pc.signalingState;
    }, false);
    signalingLog.textContent = pc.signalingState;

    pc.addEventListener('track', function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.streams[0])
        document.getElementById('video').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
    });
    return pc;
}

function negotiate() {
    return pc.createOffer().then(function (offer) {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }).then(function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
            }
        });
    }).then(function () {
        var offer = pc.localDescription;
        console.log(pc.localDescription)
        document.getElementById('offer-sdp').textContent = offer.sdp;
        offer_body = JSON.stringify({
            sdp: offer.sdp,
            type: offer.type,
            mode: mode,
            uid: uid,
            uploaded_filepath: uploaded_filepath
        })
        console.log(offer_body)
        return fetch('/offer', {
            body: offer_body,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (answer) {
        // console.log(answer)
        return pc.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
}

function startTimer() {
    timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: 0.00 secs';
    timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
        timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: ' + (current_stamp() / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' secs';
    }, 100);
};



function start() {
    document.getElementById('start').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = false;
    pc = createPeerConnection();
    console.log("Started")
    dc = pc.createDataChannel('heartRateResults');
    console.log(dc)

    var startButton = document.getElementById('start');

    startButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (startButton.disabled) {
            alert('Video streaming already in progress. Click Stop then Start to restart the stream.');
        };
    });

    if (dc) {
        dc.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Data channel opened');
            dcInterval = setInterval(() => {
                const message = "";
                dc.send(message);
            }, 3000);
        };

        dc.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log('Received data: ', event.data);
            const heartRateData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        };

        dc.onclose = () => {
            console.log('Data channel closed');
        };
    };

    var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: true
    };

    video.style.display = 'block';

    if (document.getElementById('use-webcam').checked) {
        constraints.video = true;
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
            return negotiate();
        }, function (err) {
            alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
        }).then(function () {
            timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: 0.00 secs';
            timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: ' + (current_stamp() / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' secs';
            }, 100);
        });
    }
    if (document.getElementById('use-file').checked) {
        videoUpload.style.display = "none";
        video.autoplay = true;
        videoToStream = document.getElementById('video-upload');
        videoToStream.play()
        const stream = videoToStream.captureStream(30);

        try {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
            return negotiate().then(function () {
                timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: 0.00 secs';
                timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: ' + (current_stamp() / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' secs';
                }, 100);
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('Could not create video stream: ' + err);
        }
    };
    if (mode === "validation") {
        return negotiate().then(function () {
            timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: 0.00 secs';
            timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: ' + (current_stamp() / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' secs';
            }, 100);
        })
    };
};

async function stop() {
    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = true;
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (stopButton.disabled) {
            alert('No Video streaming in progress. Click Start.');
        };
    });

    if (pc.getTransceivers) {
        pc.getTransceivers().forEach(function (transceiver) {
            if (transceiver.stop) {
                transceiver.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    pc.getSenders().forEach(function (sender) {
        if (sender != null && sender.track != null)
            sender.track.stop();
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        pc.close();
    }, 500);

    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    var timerElement = document.getElementById("timer")
    timerElement.textContent = 'Timer: Video stopped';

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

    if (dc) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dc.close();
        }, 500);
    }

    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = false;
};

function upload() {
    let fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    let file = fileInput.files[0];
    let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const upload = document.getElementById("upload");
    upload.style.display = "none";
    video.style.display = "none";
    videoUpload.style.display = "inline";
    videoUpload.src = blobURL;

    console.log("Video Loaded");
    console.log(`File is ${[file.name, file.size, file.type].join(' ')}`);

    if (file.size === 0) {
        statusMessage.textContent = 'File is empty, please select a non-empty file';
        return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    fetch('/upload', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Upload failed');
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            uid = data.uid;
            uploaded_filepath = data.filepath;

            statusMessage.textContent = 'File Uploaded Successfully';
            const start = document.getElementById("start-process");
            start.style.display = "inline";
        })
};
```

In case of use-file mode, I'm able to upload the file to backend and store the file.
So I tried creating a video-upload html element, used the **video-upload** html element to capture a stream and display it on the main **video** element.

The stream starts and gets stuck after the first frame.

This is my offer function from the python backend server -

```
async def offer(request):
    params = await request.json()
    # print(params)
    mode = params["mode"]
    if mode == "use-file":
        uid = params["uid"]
        filepath = params["uploaded_filepath"]
    elif mode == "validation":
        uid = uuid.uuid4()
        filepath = params["uploaded_filepath"]
    else:
        uid = uuid.uuid4()
        output_filename = str(uid) + ".mp4"
        filepath = os.path.join("./INPUT_VIDEOS/", output_filename)

        print(uid, filepath)

    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])
    stats = {
        "uid": str(uid),
        "mode": mode,
        "filepath": filepath,
        "total_frames": 0,
        "dropped_frames": 0,
        "analyzed_frames": 0,
        "measured_frames": 0,
        "ping_ts": "",
    }

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    pc_id = "PeerConnection(%s)" % uid
    pcs.add(pc)

    def log_info(msg, *args):
        logger.info(pc_id + " " + msg, *args)

    log_info("Created for %s", request.remote)

    @pc.on("datachannel")
    def on_datachannel(channel):
        @channel.on("message")
        def on_message(message):
            data = {}
            channel.send(json.dumps(data))

    @pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
    async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
        log_info("ICE connection state is %s", pc.iceConnectionState)
        if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
            await pc.close()
            pcs.discard(pc)

    @pc.on("track")
    def on_track(track):
        if track.kind == "video":
            if mode == "use-webcam":
                local_video = VideoTransformTrack(track, stats=stats, mode=mode)
                print("local_video", local_video)
                pc.addTrack(local_video)
            else:
                track = MediaPlayer(stats["filepath"], format="mp4").video
                local_video = VideoTransformTrack(track, stats=stats, mode=mode)
                pc.addTrack(local_video)

        @track.on("ended")
        async def on_ended():
            if local_video.out is not None:
                local_video.out.release()

            print(vitals_demo_db.get(stats["uid"]))

    await pc.setRemoteDescription(offer)
    answer = await pc.createAnswer()
    await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
    print("answer", answer)

    return web.Response(
        content_type="application/json",
        text=json.dumps(
            {
                "sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp,
                "type": pc.localDescription.type,
            }
        ),
    )
```

Here's the initialisation part of my VideoTransformTrack class -

```
class VideoTransformTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "video"

    def __init__(self, track, stats, mode):
        super().__init__()
        if mode != "use-webcam":
            player = MediaPlayer(stats["filepath"])
            self.track = player.video
            print("self.track", self.track)
            self.out = None
        else:
            self.track = track
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
            self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(
                stats["filepath"], fourcc, fps, (640, 480), isColor=True
            )

........
```

The same with **validation** mode, when I start the process, the Ice conncetion is established but the stream doesn't start.

Can someone please help me resolve this. have been spending a lot time on this from past few weeks.